# React make new array based on two other that have same key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have this two arrays:

**Array1:**

```
[
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2s4s5,
    name: item1
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item2
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item3
  },
]
```

**Array2:**

```
[
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2s4s5,
    name: item1,
    bought: 3,
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item2
    bought: 3
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2s4s5,
    name: item1,
    bought: 2,
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item2
    bought: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2s4s5,
    name: item2,
    bought: 5,
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item2
    bought: 2
  },
]
```

OK. So now I need names from `array 1` to be displayed like: `Item 1` and `Item 2`, without `Item 3`, because that item has no bought data. So I need new array to look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2s4s5,
    name: item1
  },
  {
    _id: 56s565ss2s2s2a52a52,
    name: item2
  },
]
```

I am getting this two arrays by pulling data from mongodb, and later using them with map in my components.
So how can I achieve that?

Comment: what have tried , can you show that ?

Comment: So you basically want to _filter_ `array1` based on the content of `array2`, right? If you want to filter, why don't you use `filter`?

Comment: Those `_id` values are so painful to look at -> [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: down-voted because you showed no attempt to solve the problem on your own

Comment: I have been using map. so first:
array1.map((item)=>{
array2.map((itm)){
if(item.name==itm.name){
<div>
<h1>{itm.name}</h1>
<h3>{itm.bought}</h3>
</div>
}
})
})

But that is not solving my problem. Because It displays me multiple times Item1 Item2... 
I want to have there only two divs for name Item 1 and Item 2. And in same div to have bought values in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
arr1.filter(({name: name1}) => arr2.some(({name: name2}) => name1 === name2));
```

With your data, this will give you an output like:

```
[
  { _id: '56s565ss2s2s2s4s5', name: 'item1' },
  { _id: '56s565ss2s2s2a52a52', name: 'item2' }
]
```

Comment: You should make a runnable snippet, it will illustrate the result better.

Comment: I would normally, but the input is so long. 